# Excel sheet to generate personalized Outlook e-mails

Tags: excel, email, outlook

I was wondering if there is a way to use an Excel spreadsheet containing a list of contacts with first names, last names, e-mail addresses etc. to create a personalized e-mail for each contact. For example, I wish to create an invitation which contains the person's private information like the first and last names.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a little spammy, but you could use [Outlook's Mail Merge functionality](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2008/09/22/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx) ([using Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ron de Bruin's [Mail a message to each person in a range](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/message.htm) code